# Kubernetes load balancer not getting a public ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-elb

I have a small ec2 backed (not eks) k8s cluster (version 1.23.1), running in aws with 1 master and 1 worker node. The cluster has a few services, one of which is a simple front end built on flask. I am able to expose the flask app publicly using a node port service with out any issues. But I cant seem to get my load balancer to work correctly.

**flask app deployment:**

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-ui
  labels:
    app: ui
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ui
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ui
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app-ui
        image: **image removed**
        ports:
          - containerPort: 5000
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: docker-hub
```

**Node port (working):**

With this node port I can hit the app using {{worker_public_ip}}:30000

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-ui-nodeport
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: ui
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 5000
    targetPort: 5000
    nodePort: 30000
```

**Load balancer (not working)**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-ui-loadbalancer
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: ui
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 5000
    targetPort: 5000
```

**Description of the load balancer**

```
Name:                     app-ui-loadbalancer
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=ui
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.109.158.206
IPs:                      10.109.158.206
Port:                     <unset>  5000/TCP
TargetPort:               5000/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  32343/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.1.46:5000
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Please correct me if im wrong. I thought this would create an actual load balancer in aws. Then using the public ip of that load balancer I would be able to hit the app on port 5000.

Comment: Can you please follow this documentation and give a try, Its working for me..
https://www.vantage-ai.com/blog/deploy-a-flask-api-in-kubernetes

Comment: @JijoAlexander Thats pretty much exactly what im doing minus having a mysql db server the flask app is connecting to. I have the Dockerfile for my flak app exposing port 5000 (not included in original message), I have my flask app deployment chart exposing container port 5000, and i have my load balancer service exposing port 5000 and target port 5000 of the flask app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kubectl describe service app-ui-loadbalancer` might tell you more about what's going on. Specifically, check the `Events` section. Perhaps you might need to add a firewall rule or it's error trying to get an IP.

Comment: thats one of the concerning things, nothings going on in the events section of the load balancer. Adding the description to the original question.

Comment: Make sure the account you are using (if not your own) to create those EC2 instances has permissions to create ELBs. You can also check the logs of master and worker nodes (primarily the master node), and see if there's any errors there being logged by the kubelet that might explain the problem.

Comment: Oh my god... I setup my instances using terraform, but i setup k8s using ansible. Realizing now I didnt actually set any aws credentials in k8s. How would it have the permission or even know where to set anything up if I didnt give it credentials?!? (rhetorical question)

Comment: to anyone in the future, did a bit of digging. i believe what im missing is the --cloud-provider